# RedHat + what is the variable ARC in the /etc/sysconfig/clock file

Tags: linux, rhel, date, timezone, clock

from redhat doc we can see the following:

**The /etc/sysconfig/clock file controls the interpretation of values read from the system hardware clock.**

**ARC=, where  is the following:
false or no — This value indicates that the normal UNIX epoch is in use. Other values are used by**

not clearly for me what the meaning - "This value indicates that the normal UNIX epoch is in use"

can someone advice what is the variable **ARC** target ?

on which cases need to set this variable to false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Unix epoch can be thought of as "1/1/1970 00:00:00 GMT"; that's considered "time=0".  So

```
% date +%s
1469462327
```

Means 1,469,462,327 seconds have passed since then.  That's typically how Unix counts time.

Pretty much you should always set `ARC=no` (or `ARC=false`).

The `ARC` value was used on some Alpha based machines where the clock used a different basis.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html